# How to send hevc bitstream to ffplay using PIPE on windows?

Tags: c, ffmpeg, pipe, pipeline

I have a C program that timed to generate hevc bitstreams, and I try to put the latest NALU to stdout like this:

```
fwrite(nalu, sizeof(unsigned char),nalu_size, stdout);
fflush(stdout);
```

And then use `myprogram.exe | ffplay -i -` to play the bitstream. But it doesn't work. The program will block, and finally get ffplay error:

```
[hevc @ 000002de9f2af200] vps_reserved_ffff_16bits is not 0xffff0
[hevc @ 000002de9f2af200] VPS 0 does not exist
[hevc @ 000002de9f2af200] SPS 0 does not exist.
[hevc @ 000002de9f2af200] PPS id out of range: 0
[hevc @ 000002de9f2af200] vps_reserved_ffff_16bits is not 0xffff
[hevc @ 000002de9f2af200] VPS 0 does not exist
[hevc @ 000002de9f2af200] SPS 0 does not exist.
[hevc @ 000002de9f2af200] PPS id out of range: 0
[hevc @ 000002de9f2af200] Error parsing NAL unit #4.
[hevc @ 000002de9f29c580] decoding for stream 0 failed
[hevc @ 000002de9f29c580] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: hevc, none): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, hevc, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: hevc, none, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 25 tbc
[hevc @ 000002de9f2b0800] vps_reserved_ffff_16bits is not 0xffff
[hevc @ 000002de9f2b0800] vps_reserved_ffff_16bits is not 0xffff0
[hevc @ 000002de9f2b0800] VPS 0 does not exist
[hevc @ 000002de9f2b0800] SPS 0 does not exist.
[hevc @ 000002de9f2b0800] PPS id out of range: 0
[hevc @ 000002de9f2b0800] Error parsing NAL unit #4.
```

But if I write data to a file and use fflpay to play it, it works fine. I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Without seeing a [mcve], it would be difficult to guess why your program is doing anything

Comment: ...take a few minutes to visit [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and this [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: Are you using text mode instead of binary mode?